# Heroku Deploys Completely Different App

Tags: node.js, heroku, reactjs

When I deploy it to heroku it shows a completely different site
than what it shows when I run 'npm run start'.

Why is this happening?

I am running React + Webpack + Express. The site it shows is the site I used as my starter package so I am guessing there is a line of code baked into the site that misdirects Heroku. I just cannot find it. This is my repo: https://github.com/adamskriger/calendar/

This is my webpack.config.js.

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const pkg = require('./package.json');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
};

process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;

const common = {
  entry: {
    app: PATHS.app
  },
  // Add resolve.extensions
  // '' is needed to allow imports without an extension
  // note the .'s before the extension as it will fail to load without them
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        // Test expects a RegExp! Notethe slashes!
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css'],
        //Include accepts either a path or an array of paths
        include: PATHS.app
      },
      //set up JSX. This accepts js too thanks to RegExp
      {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      //enable caching for improved performance during development
      //It uses default OS directory by default. If you need something more custom,
      //pass a path to it. ie: babel?cacheDirectory=<path>
      loaders: [
        'babel?cacheDirectory,presets[]=es2015'
    ],
      //parse only app files Without this it will go thru the entire project.
      //beside being slow this will likely result in an error
      include: PATHS.app
      }
    ]
  }
};

// Default configuration. We will return this if
// Webpack is called outside of npm.
if(TARGET === 'start' || !TARGET){
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: PATHS.build,

      //enable history API fallback so HTML5 HISTORY API based
      // routing works. This is a good default that will come in handy in more
      // complicated setups.
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      progress: true,

      //display only errors to reduce output amount
      stats: 'errors only',

      //Parse host and port from env so this is easy to customize
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.PORT

},

plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new NpmInstallPlugin({
    save: true //--save
  })
]
});
}

if(TARGET === 'build' || TARGET === 'stats') {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    entry: {
      vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).filter(function(v) {
        return v !== 'alt-utils';
      }),
      style: PATHS.style
    },
    output: {
      path: PATHS.build,
      // Output using entry name
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
      chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        // Extract CSS during build
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css'),
          include: PATHS.app
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanPlugin([PATHS.build]),
      // Output extracted CSS to a file
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css'),
      // Extract vendor and manifest files
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
      }),
      // Setting DefinePlugin affects React library size!
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      })
    ]
  });
}
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Portfolio Site",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "Adam Kriger",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.18.4",
    "alt-container": "^1.0.2",
    "alt-utils": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-survivejs-kanban": "^0.3.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "components": "^0.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "firebase": "^2.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0",
    "reactfire": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy on heroku, it looks for your compiled build because it's node environment is set to "production". It is most likely that you still have your older version build inside your where you decided you wanted webpack to send it. In your case its where this is:

```
build: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
```

So that's where your old website is at. I would delete everything in here and do another compile. Then commit and push to heroku again.

Comment: Thank you! I got it working. My build file was not pushing to Github and Heroku was referencing the wrong file.